# How to simplify Javascript Multiples if?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, scroll

Is there a way to simplify Javascript multiple if?

I have this code to make three different divs appear when scrolling to other divs but i'm new with javascript, I tried declaring all the variables first but i'm not sure how to write the if part

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var topOfOthDiv1 = $("#cuidamos").offset().top - 490;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > topOfOthDiv1) { //scrolled past the other div?
            $("#cuidado").fadeIn(); //reached the desired point -- show div
        } else {
            $('#cuidado').fadeOut();
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    var topOfOthDiv2 = $("#productos").offset().top - 490;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > topOfOthDiv2) { //scrolled past the other div?
            $("#sabor").fadeIn(); //reached the desired point -- show div
        } else {
            $('#sabor').fadeOut();
        }
    });
});


$(document).ready(function () {
    var topOfOthDiv3 = $("#encuentranos").offset().top - 490;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > topOfOthDiv3) { //scrolled past the other div?
            $("#locat").fadeIn(); //reached the desired point -- show div
        } else {
            $('#locat').fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You don't need a separate `.ready()` handler and a separate `.scroll()` handler for every bit of code. Just put all the code in one `.scroll()` handler.

Comment: This is a question better suited to Code Review.SE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of those redundant `.ready()` and `.scroll()` handlers, and put everything in one.

Then make a map of the ID of each element to be faded to its original `.offset().top` position.

Then in the `.scroll()` handler, iterate the map, and use the ID and top value of each to compare to the current `scrollTop()` position to decide if it should be faded or not.

The `if` statement itself can be eliminated as well by choosing the name of the method to be invoked dynamically using square brackets and the *conditional operator*.

---

```
$(function () {
    var tops = {
        cuidaado: $("#cuidamos").offset().top - 490,
        sabor: $("#productos").offset().top - 490,
        locat: $("#encuentranos").offset().top - 490
    };

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var top = $(window).scrollTop();

        $.each(tops, function(id, this_top) {
            $("#" + id)[top > this_top ? "fadeIn" : "fadeOut"]();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: FYI: the "conditional operator" (`<cond> ? <expr_if_true> : <expr_if_false>`) is also, and I believe more correctly, called the "ternary operator".

Comment: @GregL: ECMAScript refers to it as the [*conditional operator*](http://es5.github.io/#x11.12). It's an example of a "ternary" operator (as opposed to a "binary" or "unary" operator) because it requires 3 operands.

Comment: @squint Huh. That makes perfect sense. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: Feel free to improve the answer if you wish. It's a wiki.

Answer (score 2):

A solution should give a class to your divs and store the target with them.

How to store the target with your div ?

```
<div id="cuidamos" class="my-div-class" data-target-id="cuidado"></div>
<div id="productos" class="my-div-class" data-target-id="sabor"></div>
<div id="encuentranos" class="my-div-class" data-target-id="locat"></div>
```

As mentioned by @squint, you only need a event that do it for all your divs.

Then your code should be the following:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var $div;
    var divTop;
    var $divTarget;

    $('.my-div-class').each(function(div) {
        $div = $(div);
        divTop = $div.offset().top - 490;
        $divTarget = $('#' + $div.data('target-id'));

        if (windowTop > divTop) {
            $divTarget.fadeIn();
        } else {
            $divTarget.fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the divs map first, then do what you want. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var divsMap = {
    'cuidamos': 'cuidado',
    'products': 'sabor',
    'encuentranos': 'locat'
};

$(window).scroll(function () {
    $.each(divsMap, function(key, item){
        var topOfDiv = $('#'+key).offset().top - 490;
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > topOfDiv) { //scrolled past the other div?
            $('#'+item).fadeIn();                   //reached the desired point -- show div
        } else {
            $('#'+item).fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: A further improvement might be to only evaluate `$(window).scrollTop()` once, in case it is somewhat expensive (I tend to think of most DOM operations as expensive, especially ones to do with position information).

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
    "#cuidado" : $("#cuidamos").offset().top - 490,
    "#sabor" : $("#productos").offset().top - 490,
    "#locat" : $("#encuentranos").offset().top - 490
};

$(window).scroll(function () {
    $.each(arr , function(key, val) {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > val) {
            $(key).fadeIn();
        }else{
            $(key).fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```